# How to change the speed of playing audio in AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avplayer

I am working on `AVPlayer`. I am done with `Pause`, `Play` and `fastForward` of the playing audio stream. I want to change the playing speed of audio stream while playing. I have searched a lot, but not getting accurate direction. So, help me with this.

Comment: You should provide some of your attempts so we can help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**The current rate of playback.**

```
var rate: Float
```

**Docs**

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayer/rate

> A value of 0.0 means pauses the video, while a value of 1.0 play at
>   the natural rate of the current item. Rates other than 0.0 and 1.0 can
>   be used if the associated player item returns YES for the AVPlayerItem
>   properties canPlaySlowForward or canPlayFastForward. Negative rate
>   value ranges are supported if the player item returns YES for the
>   canPlayReverse, canPlaySlowReverse, and canPlayFastReverse properties.

Answer (score 5):

You can increase or decrease the rate by this single line code:

```
// change the rate

 Avplayer.playImmediately(atRate: 1.25)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use "rate"

```
private var player: AVPlayer?
....
player?.rate = 1.25
```

Answer (score -3):

The speed of playback depends upon the value for the `rate` value; greater than 1.0 is faster, and for slow playback, use less than 1.0.

Comment: where is the code... only description is not enough.